# How to get values from array using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have code that returns Name, Stardate and Enddate from the array below. I would also like to get Id and Project Id. I am stuck as how do I get them with Underscore.

```
arr = [{
    "Id": "03bf3cf6-d95b-448f-b3b7-c3cebfce0034",
    "Name": "Define",
    "ProjectId": "a357ff1b-cbf8-4556-9edb-445b2efb3bfa",
    "StartDate": "2015-04-09",
    "EndDate": "2015-04-22",
    "Stage": ["03bf3cf6-d95b-448f-b3b7-c3cebfce0034=define=Define"]
}, {
    "Id": "a9aed2f0-7e3b-4149-b6e3-0e3cfd33bf68",
    "Name": "Plan",
    "ProjectId": "a357ff1b-cbf8-4556-9edb-445b2efb3bfa",
    "StartDate": "2015-04-22",
    "EndDate": "2015-04-29",
    "Stage": ["a9aed2f0-7e3b-4149-b6e3-0e3cfd33bf68=plan=Plan"]
}, {
    "Id": "a9aed2f0-7e3b-4149-b6e3-0e3cfd33bf68",
    "Name": "Plan",
    "ProjectId": "a357ff1b-cbf8-4556-9edb-445b2efb3bfa",
    "StartDate": "2015-04-30",
    "EndDate": "2015-05-14",
    "Stage": ["a9aed2f0-7e3b-4149-b6e3-0e3cfd33bf68=plan=Plan"]
}];

result = _.chain(arr)
    .groupBy(function (e) {
        return e.Name
    })
    .pairs()
    .map(function (e) {
        return {
            Name: e[0],
            StartDate: _.chain(e[1]).sortBy(function (e) {
                return new Date(e.StartDate).getTime();
            }).first().value().StartDate,
           EndDate: _.chain(e[1]).sortBy(function (e) {
                return -1 * new Date(e.EndDate).getTime();
            }).first().value().EndDate
        }
    })
    .value();

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

actually ,i use the js library -- lodash , but lodash is separate from underscore , maybe have the same way to use.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

_.map(arr, _.property('Id'));      //returns Id

[ '03bf3cf6-d95b-448f-b3b7-c3cebfce0034',
  'a9aed2f0-7e3b-4149-b6e3-0e3cfd33bf68',
  'a9aed2f0-7e3b-4149-b6e3-0e3cfd33bf68' ]

_.map(arr, _.property('ProjectId'));//returns ProjectId

[ 'a357ff1b-cbf8-4556-9edb-445b2efb3bfa',
  'a357ff1b-cbf8-4556-9edb-445b2efb3bfa',
  'a357ff1b-cbf8-4556-9edb-445b2efb3bfa' ]
```

or

```
_.pluck(arr,'Id')
_.pluck(arr,'ProjectId')
// shorter ...
```

i hope it can help you~